# MongoDB if and else statements both running when they should be mutually exclusive

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I stripped down the code I am using to basically the example given on the Docs section of the website and yet still `doc` is both `null` and not `null`, if I console log doc in the if it pops up but it is somehow `null` in the else statement causing them both to run.

```
var checkDb = function(db, callback){
var cursor = db.collection('Bitten').find();
cursor.each(function(err, doc){
    assert.equal(err, null);
    if(doc != null){
        console.log('1');
    }
    else{
        callback();
        console.log('2');
    }
})
}
```

anyone seen this before? The part that baffles me the most is that I stripped it down to just the example code and still is working unexpectedly.

Comment: The node callback convention is that the `callback` is called once, you're running code in an `.each` so that function is run multiple times (one for each document in the "Bitten" collection.

Comment: This is like putting an if/else in a `for` loop and asking why both branches run for example: `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ if(i < 5){ console.log("Hah"); } else { console.log("Bah!"); }}`

Comment: There is only on document in the Bitten collection and again this was pulled right off the mongodb docs http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/query/. What would be the best way to check if x collection exists? I found some others around but most are deprecated.

Comment: You want to check if a collection exists?

Comment: exactly, if exists {//do stuff} else {//add new collection}

Comment: Why does the existence of a collection even matter? If it doesn't exist, it's created automatically on insert.

Comment: because if it does exist then I need to compare it with other data and update if necessary, if not then add a new collection, so is this not possible??